# I'm getting a SIGSEV signal when running a program on HackerRank

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I had made a post yesterday but I scrapped it and approached it with C++ instead of Java.

I tested the code on the compiler installed on my computer and it ran fine. When I run it on HackerRank, it keeps giving me **Segmentation fault**. Please find the code and compiler output below.

I read a few posts that mentioned it can happen due to illegal memory access, but I don't see where I did so. I have spent over 5 hours already and will be coming back to this in a while. Any help is appreciated.

```
struct Date
{
    int Day;
    int Year;
    int Month;
     
    bool latest(Date d){
        if (Year > d.Year){
            return true;
        }
        else if (Year == d.Year)
        {
            if(Month > d.Month){
                return true;
            }
            
            else if (Month == d.Month){
                if(Day> d.Day){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

Date ThirdLatest(std::vector<Date> &dates) {
    vector<Date> d;
    int length = dates.size();
    
    //std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        int flag = 0;
        
        for (int j=0; j<d.size(); j++){
            if (dates[i].Day == d[j].Day && dates[i].Month == d[j].Month && dates[i].Year == d[j].Year){
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (flag ==1)
            d.push_back(dates[i]);
    }
    
    Date temp;
    
    for (int i=0; i<d.size(); i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<d.size(); j++){
            if (!d[i].latest(d[j])){
                temp.Day = d[i].Day;
                temp.Month = d[i].Month;
                temp.Year = d[i].Year;
                
                d[i].Day = d[j].Day;
                d[i].Month = d[j].Month;
                d[i].Year = d[j].Year;
                
                d[j].Day = temp.Day;
                d[j].Month = temp.Month;
                d[j].Year = temp.Year;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return d[2];

}
int main() {
    int numberOfEntries;
    int res = scanf("%d\n", &numberOfEntries);
    std::vector<Date> dates;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; ++i)
    {
        Date date;
        res = scanf("%d-%d-%d", &date.Day, &date.Month, &date.Year);
        dates.push_back(date);
    }    
    
    Date result = ThirdLatest(dates);
    printf("%02d-%02d-%d\n", result.Day, result.Month, result.Year);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output

```
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 71078]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  ThirdLatest (dates=...) at Solution.cpp:57
57      for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

Sample input:

```
7
14-04-2001
29-12-2061
21-10-2019
07-01-1973
19-07-2014
11-03-1992
21-10-2019
```

Expected output: 19-07-2014

Comment: Put console output between each strings, and obligatorily and necessary with flush stdout also after each output (because it do bufferization). So you can recognise what is the code line that do segmentation fault. Then add here to question (if problem will be still not clear).

Comment: What is the sample input, expected output? What is the problem statement?

Comment: You can run the code in [Online GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) and click on Debug. It will open GDB when program crashes, then use `bt` to see the backtrace of the crash.

Comment: @kiner_shah sample input and expected output have been updated in the question towards the end.

Comment: @bingalooo Probably not the source of your crash but you are missing `return false;` at the end of your `Date::latest` function.

Comment: @oklas or better run the application in a debugger and step line by line. You can see everything the code is doing including values of variables etc. AND you don't have to modify your code with logging.

Comment: Question is about SIGSEV so actually may be exactly stack overflow. So this is more than relevant to this site name. So closers and devoters possible able to explain there position.

Comment: @oklas I expect the issue was the lack of input data and expected output. Fortunately that got corrected in time. But in general I agree, questions get closed down **far** too quickly on this site, often within a few minutes. Plus lately I've noticed how expert users are given far more leeway with sloppy questions then beginners (who are basically given none at all).

Comment: Pepijn Kramer, and John I used debugger even before msvc 2003 and before SoftICE  interactive disassembler for zx-pecrtum. I also use debugger when some crashes in deps on web app. But some times it is hard to use debugger, it does not shows something (above line 57 is not answer), or breakpoints does not show full picture of transitions where too much code and deps. It also impossible on some environments like devices or production builds. It also impossible to debug for React component sequence when some component called from react internals and stack contains nothing from user code. etc.

Comment: @bingalooo -- Off-topic, but this question could have been solved very easily by using `std::sort` with a lambda, or `std::nth_element` to get the third highest.  All of the code to do a bubble sort need not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here

```
if (flag ==1)
        d.push_back(dates[i]);
```

It should be

```
if (flag == 0)
        d.push_back(dates[i]);
```

You got your logic wrong. You are trying to avoid adding duplicates to your vector but you ended up adding only duplicates which means that nothing gets added to the `d` vector. Then this line

```
return d[2];
```

results in an illegal access error.

Plus this function is missing a return statement

```
bool latest(Date d){
    if (Year > d.Year){
        return true;
    }
    else if (Year == d.Year)
    {
        ...
    }
    return false; // this line is necessary
}
```

Comment: @bingalooo Glad to help. Time to learn how to use your local debugger. Debuggers are very good at finding errors like these.

Comment: for real! I'm gonna find some materials to learn debugging now